# How to use $ref for tags between files

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am using **Open API 3.0**, in `A.yaml`

```
# something above

tags:
  - name: user
    description: Operations about user
  - name: user_stuff
    description: API for user stuff
  - name: another_user_stuff
    description: API for another user stuff

# something below
```

Then, in `B.yaml`, I want to make reference to the **tags** in `A.yaml`, for example the tag of `user`. Suppose in `B.yaml`, we have

```
post:
  tags:
    $ref: <What are the things should be here?>
  summary: do somthing
  description: "do something"
  requestBody:
    # bla bla bla
    required: true
  responses:
    "200":
      description: uccessfully
  x-swagger-router-controller: B
```

How can I make a reference from `B.yaml` to `A.yaml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tags` keyword does not support `$ref`. All tags must be defined inline.

```yaml
# B.yaml
tags:
  - name: foo
    description: Operations to manage Foos.

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      tags:
        - foo
        - bar
```

That said, you don't have to define tags in the global `tags` section in order to use them in operations. The global `tags` section is used only to define extra tag metadata, such as descriptions and `externalDocs`, or the tag order in documentation tools.